# Installing pytorch with conda, failed to create dir

Tags: pytorch

I am trying to run some code from github, and having issues. I am trying to download dependencies , which are included in environment.yml. I ran "conda env create -f environment.yml", but got following message.

InvalidArchiveError("Error with archive /home/mchoi/anaconda3/pkgs/pytorch-1.1.0-py3.6_cuda10.0.130_cudnn7.5.1_0.tar.bz2.  You probably need to delete and re-download or re-create this file.  Message from libarchive was:\n\nFailed to create dir 'lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/for_onnx'")

At first, the terminal asked me to update the conda, so thought thats the problem but im keep getting the same message after the update. I tried to delete and re-download, but same thing happened.

Comment: Have you resolved this issue?

Comment: @ZhiyuanChen Yes I did. I had to delete everything including code and anaconda and redownload them all